# Encapsulating JComboBox to ensure fields are empty

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I have multiple JComboBox elements located across 4 tabbed panes. I would like to be able to encapsulate them into an Object[] and call `removeAllItems()`. However, being that it's of type Object I can't do this. Is there a way to put JComboBox elements inside of an array and still access JComboBox methods?

(I've illustrated what I would like to do below)

**Example:**

```
Object[] combo_container = { winners_combo_box, bikes_combo_box,
            teams_combo_box, riders_combo_box };

for(Object item : combo_container) {
    item.removeAllItems();
}
```

Comment: Declare the array as type `JComboBox` or cast the `Object`s when you take them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(Object item : combo_container) {
    JComboBox box = (JComboBox) item;
    box.removeAllItems();
}
```

But is not really a great idea. Why not array of JComboBox? Like this:

```
JComboBox<String>[] combo_container = { winners_combo_box, bikes_combo_box,
            teams_combo_box, riders_combo_box };
for(JComboBox box : combo_container) 
   box.removeAllItems();
```

Of course assuming winners_combo_box, bikes_combo_box etc. are objects of JComboBox class

Comment: I see, when creating it as a JComboBox it gives me a weird warning of infer generic type arguments. I'm assuming I would give it the type of Object. Could you illustrate this idea with a type ```JComboBox```

Comment: ```JComboBox<?>``` expects some type argument like so and that's what the warning implies. What type should this be?

Comment: O, sorry. Yeah, that is the thing with many changes in newer version of Java. If you know what will be stored in combobox is text, passing <String> is just fine. Other idea is to add @SuppressWarnings with proper name (should be available as quick fix in your IDE). But not caring about warning is not a good idea.

Comment: In this case they are just ComboBox objects that are expected to be populated with database elements (that are of type string). I don't think type String would work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Object item : combo_container) {
JComboBox tmp = (JComboBox) item;    
tmp.removeAllItems();
}
```

You can still create JComboBox array and put all the element in it. The warning is nothing but telling you that JComboBox is a generic class so it expects `<TYPE>`. But that's fine, ignore it

Comment: Appreciate the insight. After reading some more, I realized that's it better to make it of type ```JComboBox```.

Comment: Okay, that bothered me a bit. I'm so used to always knowing what type argument to give it. Thanks.